# Determine what rows are causing error in query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c, oracle-spatial

I have an Oracle 18c table that has 15,000 rows. As a test, I'm trying to run the following query on it:

```
select
    --works for all rows:
    --sdo_util.to_wkbgeometry(sdo_geometry(replace(sde.st_astext(shape),'LINESTRING M','LINESTRING')))
    
    --doesn't work for all rows (the problem is caused by: SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKBGEOMETRY() ):
    sdo_util.from_wkbgeometry(sdo_util.to_wkbgeometry(sdo_geometry(replace(sde.st_astext(shape),'LINESTRING M','LINESTRING'))))
from
    my_table;
```

When I run that query in SQL Developer, it initially runs without errors, but that's just because it's only selecting the first 50 rows.

If I try to run the query on all rows (via CTRL+END), then it throws an error:

```
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: oracle.spatial.util.GeometryExceptionWithContext: Byte order can only be either BIG_ENDIAN (encoded as 0) or LITTLE_ENDIAN (encoded as 1). Found encoding 65
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_JAVA_STP", line 68
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_UTIL", line 6244
29532. 00000 -  "Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: %s"
*Cause:    A Java exception or error was signaled and could not be
           resolved by the Java code.
*Action:   Modify Java code, if this behavior is not intended.
```

---

How can I determine what specific rows are causing that error?

I tried using [SDO_UTIL.VALIDATE_WKBGEOMETRY()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/spatl/SDO_UTIL-reference.html#GUID-5B9C48E0-197A-4A92-9D4B-1B5793B0EBEB) to find the problem blobs. But, surprisingly, it didn't return any `FALSE` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function to wrap the call that is causing issues and catch the exception in the function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION test_from_wkbgeometry(
  v_data IN BLOB
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  temp SDO_GEOMETRY;
BEGIN
  temp := sdo_util.from_wkbgeometry(v_data);
  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
/
```

Then use it in your query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  test_from_wkbgeometry(
         sdo_util.to_wkbgeometry(
           sdo_geometry(replace(sde.st_astext(shape),'LINESTRING M','LINESTRING'))
         )
       ) = 0;
```

---

In later Oracle versions, you can define the function in the query:

```
WITH FUNCTION test_from_wkbgeometry(
  v_data IN BLOB
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  temp SDO_GEOMETRY;
BEGIN
  temp := sdo_util.from_wkbgeometry(v_data);
  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  test_from_wkbgeometry(
         sdo_util.to_wkbgeometry(
           sdo_geometry(replace(sde.st_astext(shape),'LINESTRING M','LINESTRING'))
         )
       ) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it in a loop (row-by-row which will be slow-by-slow, but - if you don't have anything better, be patient - 15.000 rows isn't that much ...). Read comments within code.

```
declare
  l_geom sdo_geometry;  --> I'm not sure what datatype is result of all those
                        --  geometry functions' call; I guess it is SDO_GEOMETRY.
                        --  If not, use appropriate datatype.
begin
  for cur_r in 
    (select
       id,     --> I guess there must be some kind of an ID; if not, pick any other 
               --  column which will uniquely identify that particular row
       shape
     from my_table
    ) 
  loop
    -- inner BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END block which will "capture" error on that row,
    -- but will also let the loop continue until the last row fetched by the cursor
    begin
      l_geom := sdo_util.from_wkbgeometry(sdo_util.to_wkbgeometry(sdo_geometry(replace(sde.st_astext(cur_r.shape),'LINESTRING M','LINESTRING'))));
    exception
      when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('Error on ID = ' || cur_r.id ||': '|| sqlerrm);
    end;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the solutions provided by @MTO and @LittleFoot, I was able to determine the following:

The problem seems to happen when a WKB geometry is **3d —and— multi-part**. The `to_wkbgeometry()` function can't convert 3d multi-part WKB to SDO_GEOMETRY. I think that's likely an Oracle bug.

More information here: [Convert 3d multi-part WKB to SDO_GEOMETRY](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4499172/convert-3d-multi-part-wkb-to-sdo-geometry)

---

Testing:

**Works:** 3d, single-part:

```
select
  --Works: 3d, single-part
  sdo_util.from_wkbgeometry(sdo_util.to_wkbgeometry(sdo_geometry('LINESTRING (1 2 3, 4 5 6)')))
from
  dual
```

**Works:** 2d, multi-part:

```
select
  --Works: 2d, multi-part
  sdo_util.to_wkbgeometry(sdo_geometry('MULTILINESTRING ((1 2, 4 5),(7 8, 0 1))'))
from
  dual
```

**Doesn't work:** 3d, multi-part:

```
select
  --Doesn't work: 3d, multi-part
  sdo_util.from_wkbgeometry(sdo_util.to_wkbgeometry(sdo_geometry('MULTILINESTRING ((1 2 3, 4 5 6),(7 8 9, 0 1 3))')))
from
  dual
```

**Error:**

```
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: oracle.spatial.util.GeometryExceptionWithContext: Byte order can only be either BIG_ENDIAN (encoded as 0) or LITTLE_ENDIAN (encoded as 1). Found encoding 64
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_JAVA_STP", line 68
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_UTIL", line 6244
29532. 00000 - "Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: %s"
*Cause:  A Java exception or error was signaled and could not be
      resolved by the Java code.
*Action:  Modify Java code, if this behavior is not intended.
```